# Team foundation service - How to get feedback from people without an account

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to get people to give feedback via the feedback client who do not have a named user account on the TFS account?

I'm looking specifically for something that works in a similar way to the TFS feedback tool allowing my to specify a list of items that should receive feedback and email testing links to specific people.... but without the need for them to sign in to TFS.

Many of my "stakeholders" don't even know what TFS is and have no interest in learning or having an account.  I just need something that can...

1. Send them an email with  a link they can use to access the feedback system
2. Allow me to configure a list of "feedback areas" to guide the users feedback session
3. Will log the feedback into TFS as feedback on the specific project/iteration

Comment: The team foundation service probably isn't meant as a customer support tool. Use something more appropriate like forums or UserVoice or Get Satisfaction?

Comment: @millimoose I've edited my question to be more clear.  I'm not looking for customer support tools, I just want something that allows my "not interested in TFS" stakeholders to submit feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [usersnap](http://usersnap.com/). It integrates with TFS and doesn't require them to have an account or to install anything locally. Unfortunately you can't do this natively with TFS.

The following link will help you to integrate this with Team Foundation Server: https://usersnap.com/support/docs/apicfg#tfs

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more structured like how the feedback tool works for named users / stakeholders.  Usersnap is fine for once a product is released... but during development I'd like to target-email certain people who don't know or care about TFS

Comment: @Hades I'm not sure if anything like that exists, unfortunately. Hopefully somebody comes up with something as I'd be quite intrigued to look into it also!

Comment: Also, you have to buy the Enterprise edition of Usersnap to use it with TFS... bit more than I'm looking to pay.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear as to what I'm looking for in the hopes that someone will have an answer.  Upvoted your answer as it is kind of relevant, though not marking as answer.

Comment: @Hades Appreciated / completely understand - sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: @Hades: We are redesigning our packages in the next week - as it looks now, TFS support will go into the Pro package. If you want to try it, drop me a mail at gd@usersnap.com (Should be obvious, but full disclosure: I'm one of the co-founders of Usersnap).

Comment: @Gregor Thanks.  My current projects are not making me any money (and won't for some time, if at all) so it's still a bit pricey for me.  I was hoping there was some way to configure the TFS feedback tool to allow it to be sent to and used by non-named users but apparently not.